Approximation to the Choleski decomposition of a matrix inverse
I have a matrix $\boldsymbol{Q} = \boldsymbol{I} + \alpha\cdot\boldsymbol{L}^T\boldsymbol{L}$ and I am looking for an (approximate) solution $\boldsymbol{A}$ to $$\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^T = \boldsymbol{Q}^{-1}.$$
The problem is that $\boldsymbol{Q}$ is huge, so even realizing it as a dense matrix is infeasible muss less taking its inverse. The only things I know are $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\boldsymbol{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ where $m \ll n$.
Are there any approximations to this, either sparse or low-rank? I was able to find some pointers in the direction of incomplete Cholesky decompositions and preconditioning, but with the inverse added to the mix, none of these seem applicable. My hope would be that the known structure of $\boldsymbol{Q}$ could somehow be used.

One thing to note is that the Woodbury formula gives a formula for the inverse of $Q$:
$$
Q^{-1} = I - \alpha L^T (I + \alpha LL^T)^{-1} L =
I - L^T (\alpha^{-1} I + LL^T)^{-1} L
$$

You could technically get the Cholesky decomposition from there using a sequence of $m$ rank-one "downdates", but I'm not sure how efficient that would be to be honest
